# can I create a video chat app with Unity3D?

Tags: video, mobile, unity-game-engine, chat, webrtc

I would like to create a video chat application using Unity

So far all I have found is an asset called VideoChat but the image and sound quality is below average and on mobile it does not switch to the front camera. 
Which makes it pointless since it is called videochat..

I have found some webRTC stuff over the internet but I'm not sure if that would help me use in Unity to have conversations with front cam a smart phone(ios or android) to other devices front cam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can I create a video chat app with Unity3D?

Yes, you can do that with Unity as soon as you **stop** finding random this and that assets/scripts on the Internet and do the coding yourself.

Steps:

1. Learn C# basic.
2. Learn C# Networking (Socket, TCPClient, TcpListener and UDP)
3. Learn how to read and display image from camera on the screen (Many tutorials out there)

**Video**:

Read image bytes from camera, compress it, convert it to jpg, send to a network device using the knowledge you got from learning **#2**.

On the other side of the network, receive the jpg bytes, load the bytes as jpg, display on the screen.

**Audio**:

For the sound, you need a native plugin to get raw bytes from Mic and then do the-same thing you did with the video.

As you can see, it is very **easy**. Now you no longer have to **search**, **find**,  **found**, **discover**, **copy** or **paste** code from the Internet and expect it to run efficiently. Just like that...If your final code is slow, you can post it here and get **free** help from thousands of Unity users to optimize it. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks a lot, I was trying to figure out if that was even possible before going native. I have nearly finished everything in my application besides this video  conversation thing which is the prime deal of it.